Code for a basic python text-based game is not outputing anything, I am likely missing something basic here
So, I am currently working on a text based game for my python class in college. The basic idea behind what I am doing is having different "rooms" defined as functions and these functions are called depending on your input. But no matter what I input, I am getting no output.
To give an idea this is the start of the code (Please don't judge the writing lol, I wrote this in 20 minutes):
if __name__ == '__main--':
    while True:
        print('Welcome to my game!')
        print('You suddenly awake in a dark chamber, as you look around you realize you don't know where you are nor how you got here.')
        print('Off in the distance you hear others yelling for help.')
        print('As with any journey you are battling the unknown, you must roam if you wish to find them.')
        print('But, we get ahead of ourselves, to tell this story properly, I need your name: ')
        name = input()
        print(f 'good luck, {name}.')
        print('the door in front of you is luckily unlatched, and as it is the only way out you decide to go through it.')
        party = 1
        introduction()

From there it leads into the introduction() function which serves as the "center" of the game. (Most rooms branch off from this one.)
def introduction():
    directions = ['Northern Cell', 'Southeastern Cell', 'Southern Cell', 'East End', 'Western Hallway']
    print('You find yourself in a long hall way with multiple doors. To the right of your cell looks to be another.')
    print('That is not all however. There looks to be 2 other cells mirroring them on the south side of the hallway.')
    print('Lastly, there is a table at the eastern dead-end of the hallway, as well as another hallway creating a crossroads to the west.')
    userInput = ""
    while userInput not in directions:
        print('options: Northern Cell, Southeastern Cell, Southern Cell, East End, Western Hallway')
        userInput = input()
        if userInput == 'Northern Cell':
            if Shane_scene_completed == True:
                empty_scene()
            else:
                Shane_scene()
        elif userInput == 'Southern Cell':
            if Luke_scene_completed == True:
                empty_scene()
            else:
                Luke_scene()
        elif userInput == 'East End':
            East_end_scene()
        elif userInput == 'Western Hallway':
            if ben_key_obtained == True:
                western_hallway()
            else: print('It would be best to explore the current hallway before moving on.')
        else:
            print('Please enter a a valid option')

I have error messeges in the game, so I am expecting some output, even if it is just 'Please enter a valid option.' I have tried going putting my code through various editors and such, I have found some syntax issues and fixxed them but alas I am still getting no output.

'__main--' isn't a valid option, you need to change it to '__main__'. This entire line and the following indentation isn't necessary unless you want the program to do something different when another python program is interacting with it.
print('You suddenly awake in a dark chamber, as you look around you realize you don't know where you are nor how you got here.') also provides an error because the ' in don't ends the quotes, flipping the rest of the code. There are 2 fixes for this: change every quote in the program to double quotes. Or, simply put a \ behind the ' in don't. Don't worry, it won't change the text, but it will ignore the aphostrophe and fix the rest of the code.
A tip when asking questions is that most people would want you to provide the errors that you encountered in a code block.
Also I do apologise if I sound like I'm being a bit tough on you, I'm the sort of person who gets straight to the point and picks on things that other people are doing wrong.

If you use Notepad, it doesn't make the mistakes immediately obvious. A code editor like VS code would colour the text and show your errors in a "box" (idk) near the output or terminal.

Don't roast urself for not noticing something basic, especially if you write the whole program in only 20mins. I'm sure we all make silly mistakes that then seem pretty obvious when we work it out. For example, I was making a program to do the Collatz Conjecture to an input variable, and when I wanted to divide the even numbers by 2 I wrote num / 2, dividing the number by 2 but not actually putting the new value anywhere. It took ages to work out that I needed to write num /= 2 instead.

Be careful with your quotation marks. 'Single quotation marks' will not be differentiated with apostrophes and Python will think you have closed the string. I would recommend using "double quotation marks", particularly when you have strings with apostrophes. For example, replace  print('You suddenly awake in a dark chamber, as you look around you realize you don't know where you are nor how you got here.') with this print("You suddenly awake in a dark chamber, as you look around you realize you don't know where you are nor how you got here.")
Notice that the color of the text gives you a hint as to what Python is reading as a string.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print("Welcome to my game!")
        print("You suddenly awake in a dark chamber, as you look around you realize you don't know where you are nor how you got here.")
        print("Off in the distance you hear others yelling for help.")
        print("As with any journey you are battling the unknown, you must roam if you wish to find them.")
        print("But, we get ahead of ourselves, to tell this story properly, I need your name: ")
        name = input()
        print(f"good luck, {name}.")
        print('the door in front of you is luckily unlatched, and as it is the only way out you decide to go through it.')
        party = 1
        introduction()

For your introduction function, you haven't "returned" anything. If you want the function to produce output, you will need to specify return at the end of each phrase. eg
def introduction():
    directions = ['Northern Cell', 'Southeastern Cell', 'Southern Cell', 'East End', 'Western Hallway']
    print('You find yourself in a long hall way with multiple doors. To the right of your cell looks to be another.')
    print('That is not all however. There looks to be 2 other cells mirroring them on the south side of the hallway.')
    print('Lastly, there is a table at the eastern dead-end of the hallway, as well as another hallway creating a crossroads to the west.')
    userInput = ""
    while userInput not in directions:
        print('options: Northern Cell, Southeastern Cell, Southern Cell, East End, Western Hallway')
        userInput = input()
        if userInput == 'Northern Cell':
            if Shane_scene_completed == True:
                return empty_scene()
            else:
                return Shane_scene()
        elif userInput == 'Southern Cell':
            if Luke_scene_completed == True:
                return empty_scene()
            else:
                return Luke_scene()
        elif userInput == 'East End':
            return East_end_scene()
        elif userInput == 'Western Hallway':
            if ben_key_obtained == True:
                return western_hallway()
            else:
                print('It would be best to explore the current hallway before moving on.') 
                return
        else:
            print('Please enter a a valid option')
            return

ST6152: You want use return when the function is outputting a variable. If you wanted to return which room to go to next, then you would need to return "empty_scene" or empty_scene = "empty_scene"; return empty_scene. Also, adding return with nothing following it is completely useless. I would understand this habit if you are a cpp main. But I think that @GriffinsTale just wants to run different functions instead of returning variables.
